# How to insert a text box or any other components inside the tabbed window in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

I am developing an swing application am trying to insert an tabbed window if i insert the window i cant able to place any other components like text box how to work with tabbed window?

Comment: Post your code please, otherwise this thread will be closed as *off-topic*.

Comment: I am using GUI builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I am using GUI builder "

Drag `JPanel`s into the `JTabbedPane` and place components inside the `JPanel`s

[image]

Comment: how to set a background image for tabbed pane its showing only colors i want to set an image how to do that

Comment: Do you mean for _each_ panel in the tab?

Comment: i am using only two tabs. the screen is filled with tab so i would like to keep an image as background

Comment: Background for the frame or background the the panel inside the tab?

Comment: You should ask another question. The question you're asking is off-topic for this post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47821/discussion-between-suresh-and-peeskillet)